# How to remove ok,cancel and apply button from property sheets

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, cpropertysheet

So I tried using this code and it's not working:

```
CButton *btnApply;
btnApply = reinterpret_cast<CButton *>(GetDlgItem(IDOK));
btnApply->ShowWindow(FALSE);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please be specific with what you are asking.

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but you have an incorrect argument for `ShowWindow()`. It should be `SW_HIDE` instead of `FALSE`. You are just lucky that both `FALSE` and `SW_HIDE` evaluate to `0`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `PSH_NOAPPLYNOW` to hide the apply button in PropertySheet

```
CMyPropertySheet psheet;
psheet.m_psh.dwFlags |= PSH_NOAPPLYNOW;
psheet.DoModal();
```

Hiding OK and Cancel button can be handled in `CPropertyPage`, a handle to parent window is required because the buttons are in parent window not in page window:

```
BOOL CMyPropertyPage::OnSetActive()
{
    BOOL res = CPropertyPage::OnSetActive();
    CPropertySheet* psheet = (CPropertySheet*)GetParent();
    psheet->GetDlgItem(IDOK)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    psheet->GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    return res;
}
```

or in property sheet:

```
BOOL CMyPropertySheet::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();
    GetDlgItem(IDOK)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Looks like I only need to do this from the first page `OnSetActive` . 

Comment: WhatI did was hide the Cancel and move the OK to the Cancel position. 

Answer (score 0):

**In your property sheet:**

```
BOOL CMyPropertySheet::OnInitDialog()
{
    CWnd *pWnd = GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDHELP);
        pWnd->ShowWindow( FALSE );

        CWnd *pWnd1 = GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL);
        pWnd1->ShowWindow( FALSE );

        CWnd *pWnd2 = GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDOK);
        pWnd2->ShowWindow( FALSE );

        CWnd *pWnd3 = GetParent()->GetDlgItem(0x3021);// 0x3021 == IDAPPLY
        pWnd3->ShowWindow( FALSE )
}
```